# How to display article group by category in Backpack laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Is it possible to reorder article by category in backpack laravel? or create separate route for each category (article/reorder/{cat_id})

I am looking something like this in the article reorder page, right now it is showing a full list cannot identify the article belongs to which category.

Category 1

- article 1
- article 2

Category 2

- article 3
- article 4

[image: article table]

[image: Article Reorder page]

Answer (score 0):

To order articles in each category you have to create a nested CRUD.

Here is an article to create one:
https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud

1. Remove reorderOperation from  ArticleCrudController
2. Use reorderOperation in nested `CategoryArticleCrudController`.

I hope this helps.